# Are there public mainnet nodes? And can we simply run JSON-RPC like /network/points against them?

Tags: node, tezos-client, public-node

I would like to call /network/points against one of the public nodes. I tried **curl -s ipaddress/network/points** after I got the addresses from Giga Node https://tezos.giganode.io/, but it returns nothing. Are there basically public nodes and how can we run JSON-RPC against them?

Answer (score 2):

Giganode is indeed a public node, among many out there. However, not all RPC endpoints are exposed for performance and privacy reasons. For instance, https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io/network/points returns 403 Forbidden because they don't allow it.

If you are looking for a list of tezos nodes, you can use this [popular script](https://gist.github.com/utdrmac/2125a8514960e163837e86bc934f19b6) to get more nodes from TzKt.io and add them to your node.

Comment: Thank you! Your script is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to public RPC nodes, MIDL.dev offers a [commercial Tezos RPC service](https://midl.dev/tezos-rpc/).